# Web API CORE: "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" error during POST request SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-web-api, foreign-keys

I am using .Net Web API core and Entity Framework Core to build an API for a product store. My Product entity looks like this

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    ............
}
```

I have Order entity which is

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    ..........
}
```

And I have OrderItem Entity, which is created when the user adds the product to the Card, but when no Order is created yet:

```
 public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string UID { get; set; }

    public long OrderID { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

It tells that the user has added the Product with ProductID(FK) with THIS Quantity to his card. But no order is created yet(so OrderID FK is null yet).

And when I make the post request for adding OrderItem with ProductID, Quantity and UID to my database, like this :

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]JObject newItem)
    {
        OrderItem oItem = newItem.ToObject<OrderItem>();

        context.OrderItems.Add(oItem);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return StatusCode(200);
    }
```

an exception is thrown with the text 'FOREIGN KEY Constraint failed" on the line where I call SaveChanges(). I am adding an object with valid ProductID, the JObject is casted normally. I tried adding the same object with SQLIte browser manually, it didnt give any errors. Concerning OrderID, to which I dont give a value yet, foreign keys CAN be null, cant they?

Please help me, I can't understand what causes this issue.
P.S. I use Visual Studio 2017 on Mac OS.

**UPD.**

here is the output(I consoled the JObject to see if I get it right):

```
    Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Jobject received is:{
  "ProductID": 2,
  "UID": "6c523a76-dd6e-7782-2bc9-9b8baba36e5d",
  "Quantity": "1"
}
OrderItem casted is: ProductID=2; UID=6c523a76-dd6e-7782-2bc9-9b8baba36e5d
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext[1]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, Sqlite3Handle db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, Sqlite3Handle db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
```

Comment: Can you add more of the exception (like what fields the FK constraint it failing on)?

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7614

Comment: @Quentin, seems like similar to my issue, butI couldn't get anything helpful from this

Comment: Does the combination of `IReadOnlyList` & `entriesToSave` suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to change "long OrderID" to "long? OrderID"